# IOS: AVAudioPlayer with strange error

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, avaudioplayer

In my app I user AVAudioPlayer to play audio; it' all ok and it work fine for some minutes, but at some point it crash and this is my code and my console output but I don't understand how to solve my problem...

I have this code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    soundID = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]init];
}

- (void)playAudioReturnLettera{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                      @"returnObject.mp3"];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    [soundID initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];
    soundID.delegate = self; //<-- here I have the problem (Thread 1)
    [soundID prepareToPlay]; 
    [soundID play];

}
```

this is the output in console:

```
10:13:07.639 <0x3fbdad98> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.778" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.643 Game[155:418b] 10:13:07.643 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.779" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.655 Game[155:418f] 10:13:07.655 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.780" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.664 Game[155:4193] 10:13:07.664 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: 
"AppleAudioQueue.100.781" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.680 Game[155:4197] 10:13:07.680 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.782" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.696 Game[155:419b] 10:13:07.696 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.783" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.711 Game[155:419f] 10:13:07.711 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.784" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.727 Game[155:41a3] 10:13:07.727 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.785" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.744 Game[155:41a7] 10:13:07.744 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.786" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.759 Game[155:41ab] 10:13:07.759 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.787" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.775 Game[155:41af] 10:13:07.775 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.788" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.792 Game[155:41b3] 10:13:07.793 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.789" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.807 Game[155:41b7] 10:13:07.807 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.790" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.823 Game[155:41bb] 10:13:07.823 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.791" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.840 Game[155:41bf] 10:13:07.841 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.792" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.857 Game[155:41c3] 10:13:07.857 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.793" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.873 Game[155:41c7] 10:13:07.873 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.794" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.890 Game[155:41cb] 10:13:07.890 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.795" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.905 Game[155:41cf] 10:13:07.906 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.796" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.921 Game[155:41d3] 10:13:07.921 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.797" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:07.938 Game[155:41d7] 10:13:07.938 <0x2fffd000> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.100.798" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24

2012-04-26 10:13:10.478 Game[155:707] *** -[AVAudioPlayer setDelegate:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x546bb50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling an initializer method (`initWithContentsOfURL:error:`) on an already initialized object (`soundID`) without storing the object that the method returns.

It's a good idea to keep allocation and initialization together (and only initialize once) so your code should look like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                     @"returnObject.mp3"];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    soundID = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];
    soundID.delegate = self;
}

- (void)playAudioReturnLettera{
    [soundID prepareToPlay]; 
    [soundID play];
}
```

Comment: but I use a lot of sound, I have 30 mp3 files, then everytime I should "initWithContentsOfURL:filePath" with a new filepath, no???

Comment: An AVAudioPlayer object plays one sound, so you need one variable for each object. Whether or not it makes sense to use ivars depends on your code, but if you only play one sound at a time, then you can just move the code from `viewDidLoad` to the `playAudioReturnLettera` method.

Comment: ok I solve my problem.... I set for each player a ivar... I have a lot of ivar but finally I have not problems...thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. This will work for you. Don't Forget to add `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` in your .h file.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)playAudioReturnLettera{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                     @"returnObject.mp3"];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    soundID = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];
    soundID.delegate = self;
    [soundID play];
}
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"Audio Player Successfully played");
}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Decode Error occurred");
}
```